# Datatable stuck on "Processing" on initial load

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am attempting to GET AJAX from my Controller to populate my Datatable. I have tested my GET with POSTMAN and it provides the correct AJAX, and the success: function works correctly on my DataTable.

However when I load my page the DataTable is stuck on "Processing". I have tried changing processing off and serveSide on and it still does not work.

When I turn ServerSide: True it recieves the error:

```
jquery-1.10.2.js:8720 
GET http://localhost:51326/Table/Index?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=0&column…art=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1480635427759 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is my Controller which provides the data, as well as my class used to create the AJAX.

```
public class stockAJAX
{
    public int StockId { get; set; }
    public string ProductGroup { get; set; }
    public string GroupType { get; set; }
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
    public string NR { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string DateArrived { get; set; }
    public int? CurrentLocation { get; set; }
    public string TerminalId { get; set; }
}

public class TableController : Controller
{
    List<stockAJAX> stock = new List<stockAJAX>();
    stockAJAX ajaxTemp = new stockAJAX();
    static string csv;


    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public JsonResult getAJAX()
    {
        using (TableEntities context = new TableEntities())
        {
            stock = (from c in context.stocks
                     select new stockAJAX
                     {
                         StockId = c.StockId,
                         ProductGroup = c.ProductGroup,
                         GroupType = c.GroupType,
                         ItemType = c.ItemType,
                         Model = c.Model,
                         SerialNo = c.SerialNo,
                         NR = c.NR,
                         Status = c.Status.ToString(),
                         Description = c.Description,
                         DateArrived = c.DateArrived.ToString(),
                         CurrentLocation = c.CurrentLocation,
                         TerminalId = c.TerminalId,
                     }
                                ).Take(1000).ToList();
        }

        return Json(stock, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and here is my javascript in my View which relates to the DataTable:

```
var Json = [
            {StockId: 0, 
            ProductGroup: " ", 
            GroupType: " ",
            ItemType: " " ,
            Model: " " ,
            SerialNo: " ",
            NR: " " ,
            Status: " ",
            Description: " ",
            DateArrived: " " ,
            CurrentLocation: 0,
            TerminalId: " ",
            },
            ];

        $("#myTable").DataTable({
            "serverSide": true,
            "processing": true,
            "JQueryUI": true,
            "stateSave": true,
            "ajax": $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Table/getAJAX',
                data: Json,
                failure: function() {alert("unavailable AJAX");},
            })
        });
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#myTable').show();


        $("#myTable").DataTable().columns().every( function () {
            var that = this;

            $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                    that
                        .search( this.value )
                        .draw();
                }
            } );
        } );

    });
```

and my Datatable here:

```
<table class="table-fill" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <p1>Stock Id</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>Product Group</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>Group Type</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>Item Type</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>Model</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>Serial No</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>NR</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>Status</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>Description</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>Date Arrived</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>Current Location</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>Terminal ID</p1>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Group</th>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Serial</th>
                <th>NR</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Descr</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>T-ID</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>


    </table>
```

EDIT:

Here is my Index function in the controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection collection)
    {


        //DateTime lastMonth = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-6);

        //Recieve Data from the Select Company DropDownList
        string selectedList = collection["list"];
        //Recieve Data from the Select GroupType DropDownList
        string selectedGroupType = collection["grouptype"];
        //Recieve Data from the Show All Stock checkbox
        string selectedAmount = collection["amount"];

        //A list of type <stock> has its value recieved from the function which computes which query to use and then executes it.
        returnList(selectedGroupType, selectedList, selectedAmount);

        //Returns the view
        return View();




    }
```

Comment: Your request is `/Table/Index` but your method is `getAJAX`, *not* `Index`.

Comment: @Rob How do I make my request getAJAX then? Since getAJAX is the function which will return the JSON. Index builds my view.

Comment: Sorry, I slightly misread it. In that case, you don't have a `View` method in your controller - which you'll need to create

Comment: @Rob Sorry, I do Rob, I just didnt put it in because I didnt think it related, I will add it in an edit now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing how I was defining my DataTable as well as defining my JSON:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public JsonResult getAJAX()
    {
        using (TableEntities context = new TableEntities())
        {
            stock = (from c in context.stocks
                     select new stockAJAX
                     {
                         StockId = c.StockId,
                         ProductGroup = c.ProductGroup,
                         GroupType = c.GroupType,
                         ItemType = c.ItemType,
                         Model = c.Model,
                         SerialNo = c.SerialNo,
                         NR = c.NR,
                         Status = c.Status.ToString(),
                         Description = c.Description,
                         DateArrived = c.DateArrived.ToString(),
                         CurrentLocation = c.CurrentLocation,
                         TerminalId = c.TerminalId,
                     }
                                ).Take(1000).ToList();
        }

        return Json(new
        {
            iTotalRecords = 1000,
            iTotalDisplayRecords = 10,
            sEcho = 10,
            aaData = stock}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and my javascript:

```
$("#myTable").DataTable({
            "JQueryUI": true,
            "stateSave": true,
            "ajax": '/Table/getAJAX',
            "columns": [
            { "data": "StockId" },
            { "data": "ProductGroup" },
            { "data": "GroupType" },
            { "data": "ItemType" },
            { "data": "Model" },
            { "data": "SerialNo" },
            { "data": "NR" },
            { "data": "Status" },
            { "data": "Description" },
            { "data": "DateArrived" },
            { "data": "CurrentLocation" },
            { "data": "TerminalId" }

        ],
        });
```

However when I attempt to query the entire database as below I get a 500 server error, but if I query 1000 entries it works fine.

```
using (TableEntities context = new TableEntities())
        {
            stock = (from c in context.stocks
                     select new stockAJAX
                     {
                         StockId = c.StockId,
                         ProductGroup = c.ProductGroup,
                         GroupType = c.GroupType,
                         ItemType = c.ItemType,
                         Model = c.Model,
                         SerialNo = c.SerialNo,
                         NR = c.NR,
                         Status = c.Status.ToString(),
                         Description = c.Description,
                         DateArrived = c.DateArrived.ToString(),
                         CurrentLocation = c.CurrentLocation,
                         TerminalId = c.TerminalId,
                     }
                                ).ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Ajax call you are passing in 'data: Json' the mvc action does not contain any parameters so it won't find the action you are trying to request. Remove this line and it should work.

Comment: Try this  

        $("#myTable").DataTable({
            "serverSide": true,
            "processing": true,
            "JQueryUI": true,
            "stateSave": true,
            "ajax": '/Table/getAJAX'
            });

Comment: @ChristanP That ends up with me recieving the error:

DataTables warning: table id=myTable - Ajax error. FOr more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Answer (score 0):

for me returning
 `draw=n` 
correct version of draw from request parameter worked